# Download large files not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

hello i try to download files larger than 10M but files not downloaded

only pdf files are opend and other extensions (downloaded 0 bytes)

here is my code

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/PageItem/"), fileName); 

            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[0];

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            }

            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);

        }
```

and here is my Webconfig file

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600"/>
  </system.web>
```

note that i checked uploded files at server and they are correct size and format 
what is wrong with me ???
and why only large pdf files that opens and no other extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default IIS file size limit is 4MB.
try to add this to your `web.config` (the example to allow 20MB files)

```
 <security>
<requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20971520" />
</requestFiltering>
  </security>
```

edit1: You might check the request length size as well

```
 <configuration>
    <system.web>
         <httpRuntime executionTimeout="110" maxRequestLength="20000" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Where exactly does the <security> tag go in the web.config file? I tried just adding it just inside the top level <configuration> tag but that just gave me errors.

Comment: I found out it's apparently supposed to go inside the <system.webServer> unfortunately there's 7 of them in the main Web/web.config file and adding it to every single one of them didnt help. Grepped for "system.webServer" in the whole repo and apparently its in 63 files... Adding it to every instance seems like madness..