# IIS connection reset for all files larger than ca 1MB?

Tags: iis, connection-reset

I have a weird issue on my local IIS dev server (running an Episerver if that's relevant) that just appeared a few weeks ago when I pulled in the latest master branch. For some reason every static file that is larger than ca. 1MB can only be downloaded once or twice from the local server after it's restarted before any requests to the same file just instantly fails with PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR (and similar connection reset errors). No idea why. Theres nothing in the server logs, nothing in windows event logs, nothing to debug in the browser since the browser just says there was no response.

The only tangible thing I've figured out is that any file that is smaller than 1 MB works every time; and any file larger than 2 MB gives connection reset errors all the time. I tried to figure out exactly what the limit was adding lines to a 1MB file to increase the size and removing lines from a 2MB file to decrease it; hoping to narrow down what exact limit it was; unfortunately once the larger file was about 1.2 MB it still failed even though the smaller file still worked at around 1.3 MB; so it's not even deterministic. (And it's not just the filename because I tried it with several files that did work at smaller sizes)

I've seen several other people having similar issues:
[Download large files not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810886/download-large-files-not-working) ,
[Connection Reset due to large file upload but configs should permit upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741568/connection-reset-due-to-large-file-upload-but-configs-should-permit-upload) , etc. but nothing works (besides changing the webpack build to reduce the file size of all js files to below 1 MB; which is not very practical for debugging where I don't want it minified). Besides all the documentation suggests that IIS should send 4xx http errors; not just drop the connection without response...

If only I knew what setting that cause my server to reset the connection without any logging whatsoever (but for some reason work fine on everyone elses computer on the same repo); I could at least grep or search the git log for the configuration. (And it must be in the repo somewhere since when the problem appeared it was only in one branch but now it's apparently merged into all the active branches.)

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Is there the same error?

Comment: Yes, same issue in Firefox, Chrome, Edge, and also using Postman to just query the file directly. With or without SSL doesn't matter either.

Comment: Weirdly it seems that it works once or twice per client, so I can restart the server; fetch the file once successully in FF, then it fails on all subsequent requests; but if I go to Chrome it will work once there before failing even without rebooting the server. Not sure what that indicates...

Comment: Do you use a firewall? if so, try to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work again by changing "Maximum allowed content length (Bytes)"
from 10000000 (i.e. 10 MB) to 4294967295 (i.e. 4 gibibytes).

Completely bizarre that this works since lightly below 1MB is well below 10 MB; and it still doesn't explain why it works once but not more than once.

Maybe setting it to 4GiB which apparently is the maximum value, works as a magic value disabling a buggy size check or something?